# Pandas read json error: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I'm trying to download table with the following code:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for page in range(0, 910):
    data = {"limit": 100, "offset": page * 100, "pageNumber": page + 1}
    json_arr = post("http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/webService/getJgysLogList.json", headers = headers, data = data).text
    d = json.loads(json_arr)
    print(d)
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(d['rows']) , orient='list')
    dfs = pd.concat([df, dfs], sort = False)
```

But I get an error as follows:

Out:

```
  File "<ipython-input-21-75f1ece19011>", line 18, in <module>
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(d['rows']) , orient='list')

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 608, in read_json
    result = json_reader.read()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 731, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 753, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 863, in parse
    self._try_convert_types()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 1143, in _try_convert_types
    lambda col, c: self._try_convert_data(col, c, convert_dates=False)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 1123, in _process_converter
    new_data, result = f(col, c)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 1143, in <lambda>
    lambda col, c: self._try_convert_data(col, c, convert_dates=False)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 935, in _try_convert_data
    new_data = data.astype("int64")

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5698, in astype
    new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 582, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 442, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 625, in astype
    values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 874, in astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)

  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 562, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

How could I solve this issue? Thanks.

Update:

```
for page in range(0, 910):
    data = {"limit": 100, "offset": page * 100, "pageNumber": page + 1}
    json_arr = post("http://zjj.sz.gov.cn/projreg/public/jgys/webService/getJgysLogList.json", headers = headers, data = data).text
    d = json.loads(json_arr)
    print(d['rows'])
```

Parts of output:

```
'log_id': 'J44030020060409001', 'tag_time': '2009-06-29', 'prj_class': '房屋建筑工程', 'unit': None, 'measure': '5615.97', 'safe_sup_org': '市安监站', 'send_time': None, 'log_appl_tel': '13509605335', 'datumlist': '1、竣工验收备案表\r\n2、工程竣工验收报告\r\n3、燃气工程竣工验收报告\r\n4、公安消防部门出具的消防验收文件（复印件）\r\n5、质量技术监督部门出具的电梯验收文件（复印件）\r\n6、建筑节能专项验收合格证明文件（复印件）\r\n7、办理人身份证复印件及所有建设单位的法定代表人证明书和委托书\r\n', 'bld_name': '中建三局第一建设工程有限责任公司', 'design_id': None, 'log_date': '2009-06-29', 'log_appl_pers': '夏春芳', 'file_id': 'B0620090051', 'chk_date': None, 'bld_id': None, 'prj_log_name': '深圳市观湖园一期会所、幼儿园', 'log_serial': '2009057', 'prj_range': None, 'log_appl_org': None}, {'prj_location': '龙岗区平湖街道凤凰大道北', 'handler': '王涛', 'rownum_': '2500', 'prj_id': '44030020060355', 'tag_sender': '1', 'const_name': '深圳和记黄埔龙岗地产有限公司', 'assessor': '方凡', 'log_org': '深圳市住房和建设局', 'sup_id': None, 'const_resp': None, 'const_id': None, 'send_flag': '0', 'base_type': None, 'price': '12930.9', 'up_type': None, 'function': None, 'tag_del': '0', 'sup_org': '深圳市建艺建设监理有限公司', 'id': '306E6A20EA716A96E053020214AC7F7D', 'start_date': None, 'qual_sup_org': '市质监站', 'design_org': '深圳市陈世民建筑师事务所有限公司', 'log_id': 'J44030020060355001', 'tag_time': '2009-06-29', 'prj_class': '房屋建筑工程', 'unit': None, 'measure': '80818.23', 'safe_sup_org': '市安监站', 'send_time': None, 'log_appl_tel': '13509600021', 'datumlist': '1、竣工验收备案表\r\n2、工程竣工验收报告\r\n3、燃气工程竣工验收报告\r\n4、建设工程竣工验收消防备案受理凭证（原件）\r\n5、建筑节能专项验收合格证明文件（复印件）\r\n6、办理人身份证复印件及所有建设单位的法定代表人证明书和委托书\r\n', 'bld_name': '汕头市建安（集团）公司', 'design_id': None, 'log_date': '2009-06-29', 'log_appl_pers': '罗初坤', 'file_id': 'B0620090050', 'chk_date': None, 'bld_id': None, 'prj_log_name': '深圳平湖御峰园一期（A1-A16、B1-B5、E1-E13、幼儿园、小学及垃圾站）（不含室外工程）', 'log_serial': '2009056', 'prj_range': None, 'log_appl_org': None}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Wrap that line in a try/except and print out the value of `d['rows']`, so we can take a look at the problematic number

Comment: I added `print(d['rows'])`, but didn't find any irregularity.